# How to protect internal route from user

Tags: python, flask

Is there a good way to protect an internal route from a user? I have an application where I want to log UI errors from the client by making an POST request to an internal flask route which will log some error.

However, I don't want the user to be able to make the call on their own and log whatever they want. If a user was able to figure out the route and log something it wouldn't be the end of the world.

One thought I had is to create some nonsensical route name, like /dhjKShsj instead of /log_error to make it less obvious what this call is doing, which seems a bit unsafe and hacky to me. If a

Is there a better way?

Comment: Theoretically this is not possible. You never know what is on the other side of the wire - it could be anything from a mimicking app to monkeys pressing buttons - you only see the request coming and there's no way to know for sure where the request comes from. Obfuscating your (client side) code *may* help to some extents.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way would be to secure the route with flask-login (  https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#login-example ) and add the login required decorator to the route:

```
@app.route("/log_error")
@login_required
def logs():
```

Comment: This wouldn’t stop a logged in user from logging though, right?

Comment: That is correct. If all users need to log in then you can have a look at user roles, see https://flask-user.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authorization.html or https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/. With user roles you can protect a route with a decorator @roles_required.